# Javascript - Using promise for post PHP, get undefined result

Tags: javascript, arrays, post, promise

I'm a newbie in JS and have a little to no knowledge about asynchronous program and promise. I have a problem in getting result from post PHP as written in this code:

```
showModalLink = function(d, i) {
$('#myModalLabel').text(d.source.name + ' - ' + d.target.name);
$('#modalJum').text(d.jumlahlelangsama);
var lelang = d.daftarlelangsama.split(", ");
var lelangmodal = [];
var promises = [];
for (var i = 0; i < lelang.length; i++) {
   querystring = "select pemenang from lelang where id = " + lelang[i];
   console.log(querystring);
    var queryobj = {
        query: querystring
    };
    promises.push($.post('indikasi3modal.php', queryobj));   
}
Promise.all(promises).then(function(results) {
  if (results[i] == d.source.name) {
    console.log("1");
    lelangmodal.push(lelang[i] + " - dimenangkan oleh " + d.source.name);
    console.log(lelangmodal);
  }
  else if (results[i] == d.target.name) {
    console.log("2");
    lelangmodal.push(lelang[i] + " - dimenangkan oleh " + d.target.name);
    console.log(lelangmodal);
  }
  else {
    console.log("3");
    lelangmodal.push(lelang[i]);
    console.log(lelangmodal);
  }
  $('#modalLelang').text(lelangmodal);
  $('#myModal').modal('show');      
});}
```

I have no idea why the `results[i]` return `undefined` inside `then` function loop. Any help (or alternative ways to solve this) appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You use `results[i]`, but you haven't set `i`.

Comment: Maybe you should have a `for (i = 0; i < results.length; i++)` loop in the callback function?

Comment: @Barmar Aw I forgot about that... Now it works. Thank you for super-fast response, Sir :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have no idea why the `results[i]` return `undefined` inside then function loop.

Because you don't have a loop in the `.then()` function. So `i` has the value it had at the end of the loop that created all the promises, which is the number of promises that were created. But the indexes of `results` go from `0` to `i-1`.

```
Promise.all(promises).then(function(results) {
  for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
    if (results[i] == d.source.name) {
      console.log("1");
      lelangmodal.push(lelang[i] + " - dimenangkan oleh " + d.source.name);
      console.log(lelangmodal);
    } else if (results[i] == d.target.name) {
      console.log("2");
      lelangmodal.push(lelang[i] + " - dimenangkan oleh " + d.target.name);
      console.log(lelangmodal);
    } else {
      console.log("3");
      lelangmodal.push(lelang[i]);
      console.log(lelangmodal);
    }
  }
  $('#modalLelang').text(lelangmodal);
  $('#myModal').modal('show');
});
```

Comment: Thank you Sir, I completely forgot about that. Now it works :)